# Does imagepicker have to be a popover on an iPad

Tags: ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

It appears that different documents and discussions indicate that a uiimagepicker should be presented inside a popover, when on an iPad.

Is this really the case or just a suggestion.

I ask as it seems to run perfectly fine in the same VC as the iPhone.

Thanks,
Guy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  can create a `UIImagePickerController` and add it's `View` as a subview on any `View` you like 
For example you can add it to a `UIViewController`

```
UIImagePickerController imagePicker = new UIImagePickerController();
imagePicker.SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera;
View.AddSubview(imagePicker.View);
```